# How to declare variable conditionally, based on define value?

Tags: conditional-statements, verilog, system-verilog

I want to declare a variable, for example `reg [7:0] foo`.
I hope `foo` to be signed or unsigned based on define value.

If `SIGNED` is 1, then signed or unsigned declaration.

```
`define SIGNED 1
reg signed [7:0] foo;
```

or

```
`define SIGNED 0
reg [7:0] foo;
```

I know it is not possible to use `if` statement for declaration as below.

```
`ifdef SIGNED
if (`SIGNED==1)
  reg signed [7:0] foo;
else
  reg [7:0] foo;
`endif
```

Is there any way make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Since your macro can only have 2 values, it is much more common to check if it has been defined or not.  There is no need to assign it a value.  You just need to check if the macro is defined and use the `` `else `` compiler directive instead of the `else` keyword:

```
`ifdef SIGNED
  reg signed [7:0] foo;
`else
  reg [7:0] foo;
`endif
```

To get the `signed` version, you just need to add this line to the code:

```
`define SIGNED
```

To get the unsigned version, don't declare the `SIGNED` macro.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section:

```
22.6 `ifdef, `else, `elsif, `endif , `ifndef
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact possible to use a generate-`if` statement to do this. The problem you might have faced is that the declaration has to be inside a *named* `begin/end` block.

```
module top;
  `ifndef SIGNED
    `define SIGNED 0
  `endif
  
  if (`SIGNED ==1) begin :DECL
    reg signed [7:0] foo;
  end : DECL
  else begin : DECL // note the same block name
    reg  [7:0] foo;
  end : DECL
    
  initial begin 
    DECL.foo = -1;
    $display(DECL.foo);
  end
endmodule
```

But is more common to use the defined status of a macro to select between lines at compilation. And in SystemVerilog, you may want to use a `typedef`

```
`ifdef SIGNED
  typedef logic signed [7:0] byte_t;
`else
  typedef logic [7:0] byte_t;
`endif

byte_t foo;
```

Comment: Yes, that's why I don't want to use generate construct, because of scoping issue. To do that way, I need to modify existing code too much. Also typedef, it works based on define w/o variable, and there is no difference with declaring variable inside of ifdef directly.

Comment: @YunsungMo, without knowing all your environment and requirements, this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: You are right. I agree that my explanation is insufficient.